# what is query to change the data type of Date from string date time format in elastic search?

Tags: string, date, elasticsearch, datetime-format

I am working on an elastic search. I need to change the data type from string to date format.
The field name and its value is the date and 2020-02-01 08:17:22.438000. Now it is I  string data type. I need to change into the date-time format in the elastic search itself.

Comment: Because the date might be in UTC format. first you need to covert it into your local timezone then you can use that date. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: yes will try to convert